# How to set up a dashboard action filter to show only those records in sheet B that contain the current selection in sheet A?

Tags: tableau-api

First time poster here. I am putting together a dashboard to show progress of a number of projects which all contain a given set of milestones.
I put together two charts, a 'milestone overview' which shows a count of project_id by milestone achieved (blue) or not yet achieved (grey), and a 'gantt chart' which shows timeline of these milestones for each project_id [see milestone and gantt dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SimDD.png). All projects should contain all of the milestones but it's not always the case.

I would now like to apply dashboard action to filter the 'gantt chart' and only show projects which contain the selected milestone in the 'milestone overview' and where that milestone has been achieved (or not achieved depending on the selection), but preserve the appearance. Esentially I need to pass project_id from 'milestone overview' to the 'gantt chart', [see desired result filtered gantt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEf69.png)

Currently, the only common dimension is activity_id (milestone) so when I use this to filter the gantt, the correct projects are shown, but all other milestones are excluded from the view and the gantt breaks [see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sp5wW.png)
I've tried adding project_id to the details shelf in the 'milestone overview' chart but it then fragments the chart [see fragmanted milestone chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKZyG.png)
I then tried pushing it to the secondary axis (to sit behind the aggregated chart) but dashboard actions ignore it because then only to aggregated chart from first axis can be selected.
I also posted un Tableau community forums [here](https://community.tableau.com/thread/299164) with a sample workbook, but haven't yet had any responses. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI please see the response provided by Yuri in [Tableau community forums](https://community.tableau.com/message/901951#901951). Basically this is a one-click solution with Set Actions in the new 2018.3 version. For those in older versions, provided is a two-click solution (snapshot added). I'm not fully clear on why this works given there are no common fields between 'show projects' and 'milestone overview' sheets, yet the dashboard action still goes through without the 'missing fields on sheet...' error. Anyway, it's the best alternative to set actions.[snapshot of the solution provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEQxA.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to place a filter for the Activity ID on your Gantt chart Worksheet, like this:

[image: Gantt View]

When you go to the Dashboard, the action filter should filter like this:

[image: Dashboard]

I can send you back the workbook if you like.

Comment: Thanks but as per the problem statement, I have already tried that and this is not the desired outcome. The gantt view needs to retain ALL milestones for the project including the duration bar (see the image 'desired result filtered gantt'). I don't want to filter on the Activity_ID, but Project_ID.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but it seems odd that all of your Activity_IDs are all showing 66 Project_IDs. I would think that each Activity_ID should only show only the Project_IDs that are within that Activity_ID. I am wondering if it could be an underlying data issue, although when I looked at your data it seemed okay.

Comment: that's because all of the activities are the same for all projects but they occur on different dates. I.e. each project will have a 'commence construction' activity, but the date when construction will commence will usually be different across the projects.